# Arduino IDE loses programmer after installing Visual Micro

Tags: arduino-ide, programmer, visualstudio

I had this added to programmers.txt

```
mysmartusb.name=mySmartUSB light
mysmartusb.communication=serial
mysmartusb.protocol=stk500v2
mysmartusb.program.protocol=stk500v2
mysmartusb.program.tool=avrdude
mysmartusb.program.extra_params=-P{serial.port}
```

And was getting so annoyed with the loading time of Arduino IDE 1.8.5 so I tried Visual Micro but that didn't go well either. Now, Arduino IDE can no longer see my programmer. Tried rebooting, did a search for all programmer.txt files on the C: and deleted/updated as I thought appropriate. Has anyone else ever had that issue and if so, how did they solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalled and installed 1.9.0 as I heard that fixes the launch time (it does). I'm aware it's beta but it fixed my issue. I assume reinstalling 1.8.5 would've also gotten me my programmer back.